# Learning open GL

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I am trying to learn opengl through sites. I first see the examples and then try it out myself without seeing it, that way I will be confident about my learning being improved. However, I have been seeing opengl tutorial since 20 days now, I know the basics very basic and when I try to do a very basic program with it I fail.

I have a UIView subclass and I am trying to draw a simple triangle with opengl. However it seems like I cannot even set the background color to some constant color. My UIView subclass goes like this;

```
@implementation GLView{
    GLuint framebuffer;
    GLuint renderbuffer;
    EAGLContext *context;
}

+(Class)layerClass{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

-(void)drawView{
     glLoadIdentity();
     glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
       context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
        CAEAGLLayer *layer = (CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer;
        layer.opaque = YES;
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
        if(!context){
            NSLog(@"Could not create context");
        }
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderbuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)layer];
        glViewport(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
        [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
        [self drawView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the code above should set the background of my view to the gray color. But, I am sure I am missing some very simple concepts. If anybody could point out, it would really be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're missing glFlush() after glClear().

Comment: Even if I put glFlush() after glClear(), it does not render anything. By the way, glFlush() is to  flush all the buffers isn't it? It seems to me that buffers are not initialized properly or some very weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Cocoa Touch framework correctly. Your call to `drawView` only occurs once, before the view is inserted into the view hierarchy. Maybe if you move the code in your `drawView` method to the `drawInRect:` method this might work. A better solution is to abandon this line of programming, and use GLKit.

GLKit provides GLKView and GLKViewController classes that setup and manage most of what's required for OpenGL ES to draw your content to an iOS device's screen. It's very easy to use just by subclassing GLKViewController and implementing a few delegate methods.

Jason L. McKesson's online book *[Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)* is a good start for learning the programmable pipeline versions of OpenGL such as OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS. I'm working my way through the book, [porting McKesson's examples to iOS](https://bitbucket.org/mr_berna/ios-gl-tutorial/src), and [sharing what I've learned](http://ericberna.com/2012/01/learning-modern-3d-graphics-programming-on-ios/). Since I build my ports on GLKit they are a bunch of examples on how to use GLKit.